# Add a heatmap as a layer to a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# WPF Visual Studio 2013

Tags: openstreetmap, c#, heat-map, wpf

I need to show a map with some points (with lat/lon) of a heatmap on a map based on OpenStreetMap (OSM) .

I have created a heatmap as a bitmap image by GHEAT.NET control lib http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88956/GHeat-NET.

I would like to add the heatmap image to a map based on OSM so that the points on the heatmap can be shown on the correct locations by latitude/longitude on the map of OSM.

I am working on C# VS2013 WPF. In my C# code, I used OSM control lib GMAP.NET at:

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

This is my C# code:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap myCanvasImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(12 * 256 - (2 * 256), 15 * 256 - (5 * 256),        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
System.Drawing.Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myCanvasImage);
gheat.PointManager myPoints = new gheat.PointManager();
var xrange = Enumerable.Range(2, 12);
var yrange = Enumerable.Range(5, 15);
foreach (int x in xrange)
{
   foreach (int y in yrange)
   {
     System.Drawing.Bitmap tempImage = gheat.GHeat.GetTile(myPoints, "classic", zoom, x, y);
     g.DrawImage(tempImage, new System.Drawing.PointF(x * 256 - (2* 256), y * 256 - (5 * 256)));
   }
}
```

I need to add the "myCanvasImage" (the heatmap) to a map based on OSM.

I have checked "gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons"

But, there is no "GMapOverLayer" class in GMAP.NET WPF.

I have also checked the "heatmap-with-osm" on oms help forum.

But, the solutions there do not work for we. I need to do heatmapping on C# WPF Visual Studio 2013 for desktop applications.

Leaflet and openlayers are javascript libs for web/mobile applications.

Also, MapSurfer.net requires  .NET Framework 4.5 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2012.

OsmSharp is for routing on map.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047280/add-a-heatmap-as-a-layer-to-a-map-based-on-openstreetmap-from-c-sharp-wpf-vs2013